TestContainer is throwing error while initialising
This is the error which I am facing while running testcontainer for integration testing
12:38:50.696 [testcontainers-lifecycle-0] ERROR tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 - Could not start container
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"message":"error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Users/sheheryarumair/.docker/run/docker.sock': mkdir /host_mnt/Users/sheheryarumair/.docker/run/docker.sock: operation not supported"}


What I am assuming is that I need to change the mount folder. But I am not able to do this. Could you please help me in. this matter.
Edit:
I have added this environment variable but still issue persists
TESTCONTAINERS_DOCKER_SOCKET_OVERRIDE=/var/run/docker.sock

I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?
